# Fût-ce - what does this expression mean?

Tags: expressions

When reading LeMonde I stumbled upon this sentence "le préfet de Haute-Loire ne souhaite plus communiquer sur la sécurité routière, fût-ce pour donner des chiffres."

I found that ne fût-ce que means only if but I don't understand why the 'ne' is omitted in this case and how (and whether) it changes meaning.

My attempt at a translation: the Haute-Loire prefect doesn't wish to communicate about the matter of road security (apart from giving some figures?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're wrong on the meaning of *fût-ce*: it means *even if*, not *only if*. It can be replaced by *serait-ce*, used really more often, and simpler to use. The actual translation is:

> The Haute-Loire prefect doesn't wish to communicate about the matter of road security anymore, even if that means only giving some numbers

Also, the following two means the same thing, that's where the absence of *ne* arises:

> - ..., ne fût-ce que pour...
> - ..., fût-ce pour...

You might also check [this explanation of fût-ce by the Voltaire Project](https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/regles-orthographe/fut-ce-ou-fut-ce/).

Answer (score 1):

Your translation is quite good.

Here *fût-ce* could also be translated as

> Ne serait-ce que (pour donner des chiffres).
>
> A part (pour donner des chiffres).

Also, there's no *ne* in the sentence, probably to avoid the repetition with

> Le préfet de Haute-Loire *ne* souhaite plus

Answer (score 1):

*Fût-ce* and *ne fût-ce que* are mostly synonymous. They are the literary equivalent of *serait-ce* and *ne serait-ce que*.

> C'est pour donner des chiffres
> Ce serait pour donner des chiffres
> Ce fût pour donner des chiffres (subjunctive imperfect) : Fût-ce pour donner des chiffres.
>
> Ce n'est que pour donner des chiffres.
> Ce ne serait que pour donner des chiffres.
> Ce ne fût que pour donner des chiffres : Ne fût-ce que pour donner des chiffres.

Answer (score 1):

À partir d'un [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ne+f%C3%BBt-ce+que%2Cf%C3%BBt-ce&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cne%20f%C3%BBt%20-%20ce%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cf%C3%BBt%20-%20ce%3B%2Cc0) on voit que les deux formes sont utilisées et la forme courte est plus courante; on trouve dans le TLFi qu'elles ont le même sens (ne serait-ce que, même si ce n'était que).

Your translation should be something suh as "**even if for not more than giving some figures**".